# JSPDF not generating PDF in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jspdf

Hi I referred [This Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b629e0/creating-pdf-from-html-through-jspdf/) for generating PDF in my phonegap application but it is not working whereas when I test this example on browser it generates the PDF.
Why this not running on phonegap please help.

Thanks.

Comment: have u found solution ?

Comment: Yeah long back thanks for reply.

Comment: can u pls share solution i m also getting some problem ?? @Vishal Singh pls come in stackoverflow chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Comment: I don't have reputation to come there on chat you tell me what problem you are facing.

Comment: i m using this code http://pastie.org/10093341  but i mgeting error           04-15 12:26:38.141: D/CordovaLog(23846): file:///android_asset/index.html: Line 64 : Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined   why is it so ? while i already have LocalFileSystem,js file at this location D:\WorkSpace\myFirstPdf\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file\www\LocalFileSystem.js

Comment: i have followe this http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/01/08/generating-pdf-inside-of-phonegap-apps/  and getting  04-15 13:18:23.701: I/chromium(14520): [INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (66)

Comment: Which version of cordova you are using ?

Comment: var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '3.7.1'; @Vishal Singh

Comment: You need to add following plugins for that 
org.apache.cordova.file,
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer,
org.apache.cordova.device

Comment: i already have added  org.apache.cordova.file now ervything fine its creating pdf but the issue is i m creating pdf from html and pdf is losing all my styles and css from html so i m unable to set bold text in pdf ? @vishal singh

Comment: Try to populate all records from the javascript and for styling purpose dont use HTML use jspdf functions.
like doc.setFontSize(12);